# Changing the eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, workspace

When I try to change the workspace I'm using on eclipse, the program automatically changes from Java to Java EE (according to the top of the panel). I do not want this; I want to have a workspace that I can use for my own projects (the one I am changing from is the workspace that contains all tutorials) that is essentially identical to the space I use for tutorials. But I am having trouble doing so. Any advice?

Comment: What kind of projects are they? If you are opening J2EE project it will switch workspace to JavaEE perspective, identical case is also with Core Java projects.

Comment: Try "File -> New Java Project".

Answer (score 0):

The setting about what perspective (Java, JavaEE, Debug,...) you're using and some settings like that have been save in workspace (.metadata folder).
So changing workspace might lead perspective changing. That's how eclipse workspace working.

If you just like manage the tutorials and your main project seperately (I assume that), you should use "working set" - another eclipse feature.

Answer (score 0):

Its surely indicates that you have eclipse that can support j2ee and j2se.

If you want to do console java programming you can just try "new java project".

> You can change or make a separate work space for your project by
>   (File->Switch workspace->other) this will allow you to make a new
>   workspace or switch to other workspaces

Answer (score 0):

this is because JavaEE is default perspective . u can change it.

Window -------> Open perspective -----> others ------>select Java  (for java project)

Window -------> Open perspective -----> others ------>select JavaEE(default) (for javaEE project)